# CSS translateZ not working for child element

Tags: html, css

I'm not sure if I'm missing something with my understanding of `translateZ` but I've added a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/karan-uday/pen/poNvedo) for the same.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.cards-container {
  padding: 100px;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cards-container,
.cards-container * {
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: lightgray;
  transition: all ease 1.6s;
  /* perspective: 1200px; */
}

.card {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: lime;
}

.card-child {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(255, 230, 0);
}

.cards-container:hover {
  transform: perspective(1200px) rotateX(50deg) rotateY(20deg) rotateZ(-35deg) translateZ(40px);
}

.cards-container:hover .card {
  transform: perspective(1200px) translateZ(80px);
}

.cards-container:hover .card .card-child {
  transform: perspective(1200px) translateZ(60px);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <div class="cards-container">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-child"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The issue I'm facing is that the element `.card-child` isn't rising up out of the `.card` element as I'd like it to. The effect I'm going for is for each of the cards to rise up out of its parent. In this case, trying to get the yellow card to raise out of the green card

Comment: transform-style: preserve-3d; to the green element

Comment: Although this question has been closed, just wanted to confirm that your answer was right. Thanks for that. @TemaniAfif

Comment: it was closed with a question that give you the *right* answer (I have closed it)

Comment: Yes, yes I'm aware of that. But you still provided a straightforward answer for me right here and that helped when reading the other answer. So thank you for that.